# Do static methods block?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class defined as:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static int data;

    public static staticMethod(int val){
      ... do something with data based on val ...
    }
}
```

And now let's say I have many Java threads running in my application that make calls to the static method

```
MyClass.staticMethod(int)
```

Will the method block upon each invocation? i.e., if thread 1 calls the method first and while that run of the method is being executed, thread 2 calls the static method, will the second thread have to wait until the first execution is completed?

If the answer is no, then when would it make sense to use static data members in a un-"synchronized" way?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @SevenBits, because concurrency problems often don't manifest until there's high contention so the effort to rule them out by design will often pay for itself.  This "try it and see" approach to understanding specifications leads to code that works until it matters.

Comment: It's still fairly straightforward to try this out and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will the method block upon each invocation?

No.  A plain `static` method doesn't block other threads.  (But a `static synchronized` method can block other threads ... or be blocked by other threads.)

> If the answer is no, then when would it make sense to use static data members in a un-"synchronized" way?

- It is OK if the data member if the member is `volatile` ... modulo the limits of volatile.
- It is OK if the data member is a `final` reference to an thread-safe type.
- It is OK if the data member is thread confined.  (This is unlikely since the member is visible to all threads by virtue of being `static`.  But it is possible.)
- It is OK if something else is taking care of synchronization, or if you are using `Lock` objects for mutual exclusion, etcetera ... though you probably would say that these "don't count".

Answer (score 8):

No, that is not part of the `static` keyword. If you want to synchronize two threads accessing the same method, use other possibilities, such as `synchronized` ([method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) or [statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)), or stuff from the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.

Answer (score 4):

As you have written it, no.  Multiple threads will not block until another thread has finished  the method execution.  This is true regardless of whether the method is `static`.

To enforce that only a single thread has access to the method, you must make the method `synchronized`.

```
public static synchronized staticMethod(){
```

Answer (score 0):

No, not unless the class/method is declare `Synchronized`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html